# Static method mock in parent class for JUnit using EasyMock

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am using **EasyMock** in my **JUnit** tests. I want to mock a static method that is present in the parent class. For example :

```
Class A {
    public void testOne() {
        Map map = StaticClass.method();
        // using map code here ...
    }
}

Class B extends A {
    public void testTwo(){
        testOne();`
    }
}
```

Now, I am writing a JUnit test for class `B` and I want to mock `StaticClass.method()` in class `A`.
How to implement this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, please consider whether it's really necessary to call the static method, or whether an instance of `StaticClass` could be passed to class `A` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest (by the order of my preferences):

1. Wrap this with a concret implementation and mock the concreted class
2. Use a protected method with and extend the class with a testable class
3. Use `PowerMock`

**Option 1 - Concrete implementation**:

```
public class StaticClassWrapper() {
   public Map method() {
      return StaticClass.method();
   }
}
```

**Option 2 - Testable class**

```
public class A {
    public void testOne() {
       Map map = method();
    }

    protected Map method() {
      return StaticClass.method();
    }
}
```

In your tests you need to create `TestableA` and run the tests on it (instead of running tests on `A`):

```
public class TestableA {
    protected Map method() {
       // return a mock here
    }
}
```

Your last (and least favorite) option is to use `PowerMock`. It can work with `EasyMock` in order to mock static calls.